# Module Downloaded from Github not Importing

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging

I'm trying to create my own python package on Github so I can install it on any machine. It's installing and the module is there when doing `pip3 freeze` but there is an import error.

I've searched for "import error with module in pip" and couldn't find a relevant article specifically addressing this issue.

Here are my terminal commands:

```
>>>sudo -H pip3 install git+git://github.com/iethan/machine_learning.git
Collecting git+git://github.com/iethan/machine_learning.git
Cloning git://github.com/iethan/machine_learning.git to /private/tmp/pip-kupvue2i-build
Installing collected packages: machine-learning
Running setup.py install for machine-learning ... done
Successfully installed machine-learning-0.0.1
```

When I try to import it there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_staging.py", line 1, in <module>
import machine_learning
ImportError: No module named 'machine_learning'
```

There must be something wrong with my setup file but I'm not sure what it is.

**Update**

The issue was in the setup file.

```
  packages=['MachineLearning']
```

Should have been:

```
  packages=['MachineLearning',
            'MachineLearning.get_data',
            "MachineLearning.pre_processing",
            "MachineLearning.train_test_optimize"],
```

Answer (score 0):

You have: Installing collected packages: machine-learning
And then : import machine_learning

Try to rename module to machinelearning. 
I think you mixed up some special characters.

Answer (score 0):

The module is called [MachineLearning](https://github.com/iethan/machine_learning/blob/master/setup.py). But it lacks __init__.py. It seems there are too many bugs in the package, it's not ready yet to be installed.